# Threading: SWT events

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an SWT `TreeViewer` firing a selection changed event. 
Strangely, this event is beeing handled on different threads, depending on which thread was the last active one (it seems like).

If I just started up the application (Eclipse RCP), **events are handled on the `main` thread**.

If I opened a JavaFX view before, **events are handled by the `JavaFX Application Thread`**.

I was assuming, that all SWT UI events are handled by a dedicated SWT UI thread (as it is the case for JavaFX and Swing)?

The Eclipse RCP app uses some JavaFX Views ([e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html))

Here is a minimal working example (Not Eclipse RCP though, but Maven). It shows that all events are processed on the "JavaFX Application Thread". But I assume it is the same thread and it was just "renamed"?

The output is as follows:

```
Hello from 1, main
Hello from 1, JavaFX Application Thread
Hello from 1, JavaFX Application Thread
```

here the class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.err.println("Hello from " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    final RowLayout layout = new RowLayout();
    shell.setLayout(layout);
    final org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button swtButton = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    swtButton.setText("SWT Button");
    final FXCanvas fxCanvas = new FXCanvas(shell, SWT.NONE) {

        public org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed) {

            getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
            int width = (int)getScene().getWidth();
            int height = (int)getScene().getHeight();
            return new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point(width, height);
        }
    };
    Group group = new Group();
    final javafx.scene.control.Button jfxButton = new javafx.scene.control.Button("JFX Button");
    jfxButton.setId("ipad-dark-grey");
    group.getChildren().add(jfxButton);
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, javafx.scene.paint.Color.rgb(shell.getBackground().getRed(), shell.getBackground().getGreen(), shell.getBackground().getBlue()));
    scene.getStylesheets().add("twobuttons/Buttons.css");
    fxCanvas.setScene(scene);
    swtButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener() {

        public void handleEvent(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event event) {

            System.err.println("Hello from " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
    jfxButton.setOnAction(new javafx.event.EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {

            System.err.println("Hello from " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
    shell.open();
    while(!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if(!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

}

Comment: Where does JavaFX come in to this?

Comment: Thanks greg for commenting, I updated the question.

Comment: Your assumption is right: SWT solely operates on the UI thread. The `TreeViewer` is actually part of JFace, but this code also only sends events from the SWT UI thread. Maybe JavaFX and SWT use different threads. You post a minimal working example that shows the problem.

Comment: thanks Rüdiger, I added a minimal example.